# How do I show the cross-platform view in the browser [Ionic 1]?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I saw some photos of it but the url was cut-off and a tutorial as well but I couldn't find it anymore. Also, the Ionic documentation does not show how to do it. Doing `ionic serve` only shows the browser version. I've been searching for quite a while now and I am out of ideas.

Here's what I want to see in the browser
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ionic lab feature. Just run below command to open up side by side view, official link 
http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-lab/

ionic serve --lab

Comment: Thank you friend.